# Personalised Welcome Page With Dynamic Post Streams

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've just recently started using MSE and it's a great site. What I think would be a very neat feature is to be able to build a customizable home page on MSE so that I can see the new posts for the tags of my choice. So if I log into MSE, I see a page with say all the new posts for 'set-theory' and/or 'real-analysis' and which are being dynamically updated real-time, instead of having to click on each tag to go to its respective page. A lot like how I can modify the Google Chrome Home page to show different news streams. The reason for this is that I don't prefer the email option nor the rss option to get my updates. Neither are good for me.

Comment: Marking as duplicate, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9368/1543

Comment: Hum, actually [this link](http://stackexchange.com/filters) is slightly better. Once you are there you can select "Favourite tag" on the right box and it does what you want. The default shows the questions in your favourite tags for all SE sites you are a member of. You can set up a custom filter yourself to limit to just one site.

Comment: Thanks @WillieWong. I've setup the rules. It's not quite what I was after but near enough.